# send mail manually by mail command

Tags: ubuntu, sendmail, mail-command

After installing mailutils on ubuntu 18.04

```
$sudo apt-get install mailutils
```

I try to send email manually on CLI

```
$mail -s test
To: myname@gmail.com
Cc:
```

then.... what should I do????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press `enter` to get to the next line. It will ask for the mail subject, fill it or press `enter` to leave it blank. You can start typing your message from the next line. Press `Ctrl + D` once you're done and your message will be sent.

You can even send mails using a one-liner.

```
mail -s "mail subject" test@ubuntu.com <<< 'your message here'
```

or from a file

```
 mail -s "mail subject" test@ubuntu.com < /home/user/mail.txt
```

Just make sure your psotfix/ssmtp configuration is alright.

Comment: Thank you very much !! it works well for me.